# Setting MSS on per-socket basis with winsock?

Tags: winapi, sockets, tcp, winsock, mss

As crazy as it sounds, there are situations in life when one needs to configure TCP stack parameters manually, such as MSS.

I see it can be done machine-wide as described, for example, [here](http://www.psc.edu/networking/projects/tcptune/OStune/winxp/winxp_stepbystep.html). But I need a way to configure it on per-tcp-socket basis.

Answer (score 2):

That should be standard `setsockopt` with `TCP_MAXSEG`. Just remember that this has to be done before connection is initiated (i.e. before `connect` or `listen`) and that TCP stack might change the actual value according to path MTU.

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling `setsockopt()` with TCP_MAXSEG as is implied to be possible at the bottom of [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms819736%28v=MSDN.10%29.aspx). But what's strange is that the TCP_MAXSEG is not a valid optname to supply to [`getsockopt()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738544%28VS.85%29.aspx). So maybe it can be set but not retrieved? I guess give it a try and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks, will check. Perhaps it is defined in some other version of platform sdk headers...

Answer (score 0):

I think windows may does not allow you to adjust MSS per socket.

Here's the test sample:
Just call `setsockopt` with `TCP_MAXSEG`.
    `#include <ws2tcpip.h>`

```
`int mss = 512;`  
`setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_MAXSEG, (char*)&mss, sizeof(mss);`
```

Set it before `connect` or `listen`.

I tested it with vs2015 on windows10. This code can pass the compile in VS2015, but can not run. Windows will give a error `WSAENOPROTOOPT` when it's running.